# How to add an element into the HTMLCollection in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTMLCollection Object which i can use to manipulate the content of the HTMLCollection. I would like to know the way out to add a div element to the first, last or to any specific index of the HTMLCollection. Please suggest something.
Here nDivs is the HTML Collection.

```
    var Div = document.createElement('div');
    for(i=0; i<9; i++){
        Div.appendChild(nDivs[0].children[0]);
    }
    Div.id = nDivs[0].id;
    nDivs[0].parentNode.removeChild(nDivs[0]);

    nDivs.appendChild(Div); //this is creating problem..need an alternative to this
    document.getElementById("ABC").appendChild(nDivs[nDivs.length - 1]);
```

Comment: I have tried a lot many approaches...converting the collection into an array and then proceeding but that doesn't serve my purpose. I am able to remove an element from that collection but adding an element is not happening.

Comment: Maybe copy some code here that sets up your HTMLCollection, and shows exactly what you want

Comment: I suggest including some code in your question, and pointing out specifically what your difficulty is.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLCollection)

> `HTMLCollection` is an interface representing a generic collection of
>   elements (in document order) and offers methods and properties for
>   traversing the list.

Because its an interface, you're restricted to interacting with an `HTMLCollection` via its [methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLCollection#Methods). There are no methods there to modify the object, only to read it. **You'll have to manipulate the DOM some other way**.

Here are some suggestions using pure JS, but I highly recommend [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for such tasks. Assume we're working with a new element `newDiv` and the `HTMLCollection` `document.forms`:

**insert before** `forms[1]`:

```
forms[1].parentNode.insertBefore(newDiv, forms[1]);
```

**insert after** `forms[1]`:

```
// there is no insertAfter() so use the next sibling as reference element
forms[1].parentNode.insertBefore(newDiv, forms[1].nextSibling);
```

**replace** `forms[1]`:

```
forms[1].parentNode.replaceChild(newDiv, forms[1]);
```

Documentation and examples for [insertBefore()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.insertBefore), [replaceChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.replaceChild), [nextSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.nextSibling), and [parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.parentNode).

Comment: if `forms` is the parent node already, why do you do `forms[1].parentNode.insertBefore(...)` and not simply `forms.insertBefore(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert your new Elements in the DOM directly. You cannot manipulate a read-only HTMLCollection directly. But don't worry, your HTMLCollection (stored in a variable) will update accordingly:

```js
// DOM helper functions:
const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const elNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);


// Cache a reference to the wrapper parent Element 
const elParent = el("#parent-a");

// Cache a live HTMLCollection:
const collItems = elParent.children;

// Insert new elements in the DOM:
elParent.prepend(elNew("div", {textContent: "Item First (New)"}));
elParent.append(elNew("div", {textContent: "Item Last (New)"}));

// Check if the collection is live:
console.log(collItems.length); // 5
```

```html
<div id="parent-a">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

as you can see above (contrary to if you used i.e: `const collItems = elParent.querySelectorAll(".item");`) the live HTMLCollection reports that is has 5 children in total.

Also, you can see how to append and prepend an item as *first* or *last*.
To answer your other question:

> *"how to insert at a specific index"*

you can use:

```js
// DOM helper functions:
const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const elNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);
const insertAtIndex = (idx, parent, ...els) => {
  els = els.flat();
  const ch = parent.children;
  if (idx >= ch.length) parent.append(...els);
  else ch[Math.max(idx, 0)].before(...els);
};

// Cache a reference to the wrapper parent Element 
const elParent = el("#parent-a");
// Cache a live HTMLCollection:
const collItems = elParent.children;
// Insert element/s at index
insertAtIndex(
  2,
  elParent,
  elNew("div", {textContent: "NEW item 1"}),
  elNew("div", {textContent: "NEW item 2"}),
);

console.log(collItems.length); // 4
```

```html
<div id="parent-a">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
</div>
```