# TypeScript or JS- How to select an element and all its children into a HTMLCollection?

Tags: javascript, typescript, htmlcollection

**Updated**
The code I have come up with is:

```
<section id="Test">
   <header>Welcome</header>
   <p>This is a test</p>
   <div>Nothing here</div>
</section>

var element =  document.getElementById("Test");
var elements = <HTMLCollection>element.getElementsByTagName("*");
```

I want the collection to include `<section>`, `<header>`, `<p>`, and `<div>` the above code only has `<header>`, `<p>`, and `<div>`. Is there anyway I can add the `<section>` itself to the collection?

The problem is that I want to include the element itself into the elements collection. I know I can use outerHTML and put it in a temp container and then get all the element inside from that but i'm looking for a cleaner way.

Comment: *" include the element itself"* - not sure I get what you're asking...

Comment: You're going to have to include more information, and some HTML code, if you want us to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: The node you get from `getElementById()` will retain its `childNodes` / `children `; so... Just retrieve that one node and access its children directly when you need to?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856281/how-to-add-an-element-into-the-htmlcollection-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a comma-separated list with [**`querySelectorAll`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), where the first item is the element itself.

This Snippet uses your HTML to retrieve section `Test` and its children: `header`, `p`, and `div`:

```js
var elements= document.querySelectorAll('#Test, #Test *');
console.log(elements.length); //4
```

```html
<section id="Test">
   <header>Welcome</header>
   <p>This is a test</p>
   <div>Nothing here</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I am looking for except I want it to be a little more universal. So it can work with any tag dynamically. In this case you know it is a UL tag. Lets pretend we don't know what tag the element is. in other words in a function where the element is passed in how can I get the element itself and its children into a html collection.

Comment: I've updated my answer.  To use `querySelectorAll` with an id, prepend a pound sign to the id.